# Exception Error at the line BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

Tags: c++, boost-test

i have a problem with the boost-test from my teacher.
When i'm debugging my project i get an error at this Line:

```
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

The Exception is the following:

0x7521b727 (KernelBase.dll) in homework2.exe: 0xC0020001: The string binding is invalid.

i'm using Visual Studio 2010 ultimate and Win7 Professional (with all updates) 
This Bug is very annoying,because i get an Zombie console Window when the exception is thrown.

sorry for my English ;)

Edit: My test Code

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <string>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( easy_stringtest)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( length_test)
{
    std::string s("xyz");
    BOOST_CHECK(s.length() ==3);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( same)
{
    std::string s("abc");

    BOOST_CHECK(s == "abc");
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Edit: I have fould my fault... The IDE Option /clr was turned on, turn it off and you will have no error :D

Comment: Talk to your teacher, your code has nothing to do with the exception.

Comment: ok thx, so i will reinstall my boost, maybe there i get an error

Comment: @demonking: Please don't post links to pastebin. Post the relevant code directly. This prevents dead links and is more useful when searching SO.

Comment: i have edited my post, so that some other Test has the same problem.
because this problem still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my include; my teacher told me that the problem was with my binaries.

When someone else has the same problem **here is the solution:**

New Code:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <string>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( easy_stringtest)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( length_test)
{
    std::string s("xyz");
    BOOST_CHECK(s.length() ==3);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( same)
{
    std::string s("abc");

    BOOST_CHECK(s == "abc");
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```